# Currently studying series in Calc 2 and got a question as to their relation to the $R_0$ of a virus.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Firstly, please forgive me if any of what I'm writing is wrong as I'm still pretty new to this stuff.

With the current ongoing pandemic, we hear a lot about $R_0$ and its importance in managing a disease. From what I understand, $R_0$ refers to "the expected number of cases directly generated by one case in a population where all individuals are susceptible to infection (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_reproduction_number).

So what I take from this is, let's assume $R_0$ is 3 and no variables are in place to decrease/increase it. So, one person infects 3 people, these 3 people infect another 9 people and so on so forth.

Doesn't this resemble the following geometric series?

$$\sum_{n=1}^k 3^{n-1}$$

If this is true, wouldn't we be able to predict the number of expected infections, depending on what k we are using:

$$S_n = \frac{a(1-r^k)}{1-r}$$

I know this is a pretty simplified view of what actually goes on, I'm just trying to relate it to what I'm learning.

Comment: formatting note:  type `$R_0$` to get $R_0$

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely right in saying that **your assumptions** result in a geometric progression, though oversimplified, as you stated. But in saying that

> ...wouldn't we be able to predict the number of expected infections, depending on what k we are using...

How can you "predict" something if you are **assuming** *absolutely everything* about the problem in concern?! 
Or maybe you are trying to ask something else, but couldn't word it properly.

Answer (score 1):

In this *extremely* simplified model, yes. However, there are a **ton** of factors at play here. Perhaps the most basic one this model neglects is what our index $n$ even means in the real world. Is it really accurate to say everyone takes exactly the same amount of time to infect their three other allotted people? How would we know what our $k$ even is?